# Play PHP Video file in a continuous loop

Tags: video, playback, continuous

How to play a video file in a continuous loop, as the page is requested, with php?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably u will be using some player to play the video files and already there should be an easy option within the player configurations to play in loop..

Try to read the manual/help document of the player you are using...